# How can i use map() and find() in the same codeline

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 files, like in the example:

player.js - for now, I use only one item in the object

```
const players = {
  playerId: '5555',
  playerName: 'JHON',
  playerTeams: [real, barcelona, liverpol],
};
```

Team.js

```
const Teams = [
  { name: 'real', teamImageSrc: '' },
  { name: 'barcelona', teamImageSrc: '' },
  { name: 'liverpol', teamImageSrc: '' },
];
```

My purpose at this stage of the project is to check that my UI code display the data well, and later I will correct the logic behind the UI, and right now what I'm trying to do is to display the list of teams the player is member, This task that I have managed to do using map () but I need to locate the image of each value I got from the map () like in the example below:

```
class GridPlayerTeamsMembership extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <List>
          {players.playerTeams.map(value => (
            <ListItem dense button className={classes.listItem}>
              <Avatar ? />
              <ListItemText primary={` ${value}`} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

GridPlayerTeamsMembership.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(GridPlayerTeamsMembership);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a function like this:

```
teamImage = (teamName) => Teams.find(t=>t.name===teamName).teamImageSrc
```

And use the teamImage like this:

```
<Avatar src={this.teamImage(value)} />
```

Comment: That's a nice and clean solution. Initially I thought that filter() would be a better solution, but I googled it and it seems that you my friend, are correct. Find() stops looping through the array after the first item is found, where filter continues until the loop has ended.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I succeeded but without the this.

```
class GridPlayerTeamsMembership extends React.Component {

render() {
const { classes } = this.props;
teamImage = (teamName) => Teams.find(t=>t.name===teamName).teamImageSrc

return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <List>
          {players.playerTeams.map(value => (
            <ListItem key={value} dense button className={classes.listItem}>
              <img src={teamImage(value)} className={classes.img} />
              <ListItemText primary={` ${value}`} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

GridPlayerTeamsMembership.propTypes = {
classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(GridPlayerTeamsMembership);
```